# Disable double click in Angular 11 prime ng slider

Tags: angular, rangeslider

range prime ng slider is used in angular web app. When clicked on right side min pointer is moving but not the max pointer. Please advise.

Comment: Can share the code?

Comment: <p-slider [(ngModel)]="rangeValues" [range]="true" [min]="minRangeLimit" [max]="maxRangeLimit" [step]="rangeSteps" (onSlideEnd)="onRangeSliderMoved()" [disabled]="((minRangeLimit == 0 && maxRangeLimit == 0) ||(minRangeLimit == maxRangeLimit) || minRangeLimit == undefined || minRangeLimit == null  || maxRangeLimit == undefined || maxRangeLimit == null)"></p-slider>

Comment: min and max range balls are moving for sliding. But if user double clicks after right side ball anywhere in slide line its not automatically sliding. How ever when double clicked on slide line on left, min slide ball moves. Can we disable this double click feature and only min-max ball slide only to be allowed